# Using VBA to scrape top line of table information

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

New to this and just trying to learn using a bit on scraping targeted data from the web. I have been slowly putting together stuff, but have hit a snag, and wondering what I am missing.

I am looking to scrape only the top row of data from a list of URL's I have saved into a spreadsheet, the main webpage is locked behind a login, and I have that script working, and I can then cycle through the targeted pages using the below:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As Object, link As Variant
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


Rows = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
links = wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & Rows)

With IE
    .Visible = True
    For Each link In links
        .navigate (link)
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5")): Wend
    Next link
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

What I am trying to do is once a page is loaded, it waits 5 seconds, then moves to the next page. On the page there is a table, and I am trying to pull just the top line (lines in each pages table will vary, but all will have a top line).
HTML code is below for this table:

```
<table class="tblStandard-stripes small_text" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                    </thead>
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>104</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td class="name"><"/game/club">Adelaide</a></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>16</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>6.60</td>
                    <td class="ph_gbh">0</td>
                    <td class="ph_FMR">2</td></tr><tr class="list_data_row_1">
                    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to pull back the all the numbers basically, so 104,27,Adelaide,0,16 all the way to the last number being 2, and to place them in the next row of an excel sheet named data.

I have the below VBA to try and do this, but it won't get past the 'getelementsbyclass' tag I have:

```
'Table Headers
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Season"
ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Day"
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Club"

Set HTMLTable = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("tblStandard-stripes small_text")(0)
Set TBody = HTMLTable.Children(1)
RowIndex = 2
For Each Row In TBody.Children
  ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value = Row.Children(0).innerText
  ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value = Row.Children(1).innerText
  ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value = Row.Children(2).innerText
  RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: what error do you get in the line `Set HTMLTable = ...`?

Comment: IIRC (could be wrong) but with IE, it doesn't like compound class names very well when used with `getElementsByClassName(...)`. Try just using `.getElementsByClassName("tblStandard-stripes")(0)` and see where that gets you. On a side now, _"but it won't get past the ..."_ is not an error code. Please provide error details (code + description) when asking for debugging help. Error codes (or even the lack thereof) are extremely helpful in debugging coding issues. Otherwise you would get a generic error **"Your code doesn't work"** if they weren't meant to be examined.

Comment: Compound class names are not a problem for `getElementsByClassName` with IE. We need to see the error message.

Comment: Sorry All, the error code is 'Run-time error '424'': Object required.

Comment: Either you need a longer wait condition before attempting the SET line, or the html is dynamic and changes over time, or it is inside a parent frame/iframe element. If you execute code line by line using F8 (or putting  a long wait before failing line) resolve the problem?

Comment: Actually, I think my issue is not knowing where to put the second half of the code. The top section works and cycles through all pages before hitting the second part of the code to do the table scrape. I am not sure where to place the lines so that it's one continuous piece.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of the links? And are you now saying you don't get 424 error on SET line?